# how to put the array values into a list of buttons that opens new views based what is clicked

Tags: swift, swiftui

as you can see the HStack is very redundant.
I want to have an array of some type that contains both the image and the text
But I do not know how to put that array into the list, more importantly I do not know how to recognize which element in the array was clicked and open a new view based on what is clicked

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {

// as you can see the HStack is very redundant.
// I want to have an array of some type that contains both the image and the text
// But I do not know how to put that array into the list, more importantly I do not know how to recognize which element in the array was clicked and open a new view based on what is clicked
                    HStack {
                        Image("someImage")
                        .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        NavigationLink (destination: SomeView()) {
                            Text("SomeText").foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .bold()
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image("Image2")
                            .resizable()
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                        NavigationLink(destination: image2()) {
                            Text("text2").foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .bold()
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Image("image3")
                            .resizable()
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                        NavigationLink(destination: view3()) {
                            Text("view3").foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .bold()
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("list")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a 3 different arrays or a Model, I'll demonstrate it with the first approach with arrays since your question was specific about arrays.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let views: [AnyView] = [AnyView(SomeView()), AnyView(Image2()), AnyView(View3())]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0...2, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink (destination: self.views[index]) {
                        ListRowView(index: index)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("List")
        }
    }
}



#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif

struct ListRowView: View {
    var index: Int
    let imageNames: [String] = ["cart","star","book"]
    let textList: [String] = ["SomeText","text2","view3"]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: self.imageNames[index])
                .resizable()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
            Text(self.textList[index])
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .bold()
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SomeView")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .bold()
     }
}

struct Image2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Image2")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .bold()
     }
}

struct View3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View3")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .bold()
     }
}
```

The first array is representing your destination views with its type as `AnyView`, the another two arrays are a regular `String` arrays representing your image names and the text. I used `systemName` images for demonstration purposes only and you can use your own image names from the assets.

I hope it is what you are looking for, and if the answer worked for you please accept it as an answer. Also do not hesitate to engage in comments!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
public struct ImageTextView<Destination> : Hashable where Destination: View {

    public static func == (lhs: ImageTextView<Destination>, rhs: ImageTextView<Destination>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uuid == rhs.uuid
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
           return uuid.hashValue
       }

    var uuid = UUID().uuidString
    var image: Image
    var text : String
    var destination: Destination

    init(image: Image, text: String, destination: Destination) {
        self.image = image
        self.text = text
        self.destination = destination
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text ("navigation target")
    }
}

let rows  = [
    ImageTextView(image: Image("someImage"), text: "SomeText", destination: SomeView())
//    ImageTextView(image: Image("image2"), text: "text2", destination: SomeView())
     ]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {

// as you can see the HStack is very redundant.
// I want to have an array of some type that contains both the image and the text
// But I do not know how to put that array into the list, more importantly I do not know how to recognize which element in the array was clicked and open a new view based on what is clicked
                    ForEach (rows, id: \.self) { row  in

                        HStack {
                            row.image
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                            NavigationLink (destination: SomeView()) {
                                Text(row.text).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .bold()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("list")
            }
        }
    }
}
```